# Delete Tags: "premillenialism" and "amillenialism" (they're spelled wrong)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Please delete "premillenialism" tag and "amillenialism" tag; they're spelled wrong.

I've already created replacement tags; "premillen**n**ialism" and "amillen**n**ialism" and changed all the questions over to use those tags instead.

Answer (score 4):

Done! Well, they haven't quite been deleted yet, but give it a day or so and they'll be gone because they're not used on any questions. Furthermore, the misspellings are now synonymized to the correct spellings, so the wrong ones can't be added to new questions either.

Also, for future reference **don't** retag all of the questions yourself. The mods' tag merge tool retags the questions without bumping them, so you don't end up with a bunch of old questions on the front page solely because they were retagged. In this case, it was okay because you only edited 12 questions, but in the future, if there are more than, say, six questions that need to be retagged, please let the mods know instead (make a meta post like you did). :)

Comment: I'm the one who suggested he could retag them himself, since there were so few of them.  If that was bad advice, blame me, not Jas3.1!

Comment: @Flimzy: YOU ARE DULY BLAMED! Ha, I kid. Mostly. In all seriousness, 12 is a relatively low number, so that's not too bad, but it *did* take up about half the page. It's a bit weird to see a dozen questions in a row about the same topic...